# If statement issue, toPrecision not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Coding seems to be having no effect? when winner is more than 10 digits it does not change

```
if(winner.length > 10){
   winner = winner.toPrecision(10);
   $('#podiumBox').val(winner)
   winner1 = winner;
}else{
   $('#podiumBox').val(winner)
   winner1 = winner;
}
```

Comment: If you're able to check the length, it's probably a string, and strings don't have a `toPrecision()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `winner` is a number, then `winner.length` is undefined, and so `winner.length > 9` is false, causing the `else` block to execute.

If `winner` is a string, then `winner.toPrecision(9)` would cause a TypeError - check your javascript console.

Either way, this should cover it:

```
if( winner.toString().length > 9 ) winner = parseFloat(winner).toPrecision(9);
$('#podiumBox').val(winner)
winner1 = winner;
```

Answer (score 2):

`winner` is a string (inferred by usage of the `length` property), while `toPrecision` is a method of `Number`. JavaScript has loose typing, yes, but you still need to cast it in order to access the method:

```
Number(winner).toPrecision(9)
```